# A piece of my code is showing on my site. I'm thinking I used the wrong syntax

Tags: php

I'm having a little difficulty with the syntax I think. A line of my code seems to keep displaying. The line of code that keeps displaying is: if($affected_rows >= 1) {?< 
What could possibly be wrong? Where you see the comment:  //---- checks if there are rows that got updated. if 0 rows then there is a duplicate and will not show the lightbox code
 this is where the problem begins.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<title>NetDocs - The Network Documentation Webpage "Your Resource For BMF     Documentation"</title>

</HEAD>



  <body>
<?PHP

$link = mssql_connect('localhost', 'mssql_user', 'password');
if(!$link) {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mssql_error());
}

//Function to get the vistors IP address
function getUserIP()
{
   $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
   $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
   $remote  = $SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

   if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
   {
    $ip = $client;
   }
   elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
   {
    $ip = $forward;
   }
   else
   {
    $ip = $remote;
   }

   return $ip;
}

//check if this is the first time visit
if(!isset($user_ip){

$user_ip = getUserIP();
$sql ="INSERT INTO USER_IP ('user_ip') VALUES ('" . $user_IP . "');";
$results = mssql_query($sql);
$Affected_Rows = mssql_num_rows($result);
}

//---- checks if there are rows that got updated. if 0 rows then there is a duplicate and will not show the lightbox code

if($affected_rows >= 1) {?< // This is what keeps showing on my site just the 1) {<

<script src="http://cdn.jotfor.ms/static/feedback2.js?3.1.881" type="text/javascript">
new JotformFeedback({
formId:'33084654629158',
base:'http://jotform.us/',
windowTitle:'Registration Form',
background:'#FFA500',
fontColor:'#FFFFFF',
type:false,
height:500,
width:700,
openOnLoad:true
});
</script>


<?php
}
mssql_close($link);
?>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

The closing tag is wrong:

```
<?php ... ?>
```

Note the **>** at the end.

/edit: Unrelated to the question, but just in case you didn't know this:
If you're mixing PHP with HTML (which itself is a concept you might want to avoid), you might want to consider using the [alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php). That way you don't have a closing `}` in your code, which might improve readability.

```
<?php if (true) : ?>
    <p>html output</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't check rest of your code but there should be

```
if($affected_rows >= 1) { ?>
```

Instead of

```
if($affected_rows >= 1) {?<
```

Answer (score 0):

`if($affected_rows >= 1)`

should be:

`if($Affected_Rows >= 1)`

here is a simple test:

```
$Affected_Rows = 'Hello World';

echo $affected_rows;
```

You'll receive an undefined variable.

Also you need to properly close the `php` tag:

`if($Affected_Rows >= 1){?>`

Also the following is missing a closing parenthesis:

`if(!isset($user_ip){`

should be:

`if(!isset($user_ip)){`

Comment: I've updated both and I can still see part of my code on my website.